# How to create a lower diagonal matrix with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

How can I generate a lower diagonal matrix of dynamic size with **Numpy**?
For example, if the size `n` of the matrix is `4` I would like to obtain such a matrix:

```
| 0 0 0 0 |
| 1 0 0 0 |
| 0 1 0 0 |
| 0 0 1 0 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the shortest way to be using [np.eye](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html):

```
import numpy as np

n = 4
np.eye(n, k=-1, dtype=int)
```

The output is:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create it, by first creating a matrix with zeros, and then fill in the ones:

```
import numpy as np

# create matrix with zeros
n=4
mat = np.zeros((n,n))

# create indexes for where the 1s belong
rows = np.arange(1,n)
cols = np.arange(n-1)

# fill in the 1s
mat[rows, cols] = 1
```

output:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]]
```